# DIV y ROW Boostrap

Tags: bootstrap, div

Estoy iniciando en Boostrap y estoy intentando hacer un ejercicio de filas y columnas  pero no se donde estoy fallando

```
<div class="row">
<div class="column">Hola mundo</div>
</div>
```

se supone que se me debe alinear un poco hacia la derecha pero no lo hace

Answer (score 1):

seguramente el alineado que te referías podría ser por la clase *.container* que agrega unos padding y margenes.

Te recomendarías que veas mas ejemplo, el sistema de grilla de boostrap funciona a través de 12 columnas, cada elemento que crees ocupara la cantidad de columnas que tu definas asignandole al lado de la clase *.col-cant_de_columnas*. Aquí un pequeño ejemplo

```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-6 caja_roja"></div>
          <div class="col-6 caja_azul"></div>  
      </div>
    </div>
```

También te recomendaría que te fijes los tamaños de pantallas que maneja, para poder utlizar en diferentes tamaños de pantallas.

[Documentación de Boostrap - Grid](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/)

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que indicarle cuantas "columnas" del grid de 12 columnas tomará.

Bootstrap utiliza la siguiente sintaxis: `<div class="col-md-6">` donde md será el ancho minimo de un dispositivo para que tome esa cantidad de columnas, y 6 la cantidad de columnas que tomará tu elemento.

Comment: Michi, bienvenido, te saludo y te comento que es importante realices el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Para responder tomo como base el documento [answer].

Answer (score 0):

bueno primero que nada debes revisar la documentación de Boostrap [Ejemplos](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/overview/)

Ahora lo normal es la siguiente estructura

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">

      Texto

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Tambien debes tener en cuenta que la clase por ej: **"col-12"** es para el 100% de ancho y **"col-6"** el 50%. Esto lo podes modificar y variar el ancho según la resolución con por ejemplo **"col-xs-numero, col-sm-numero, col-md-numero, col-lg-numero"**